# why hierarchyview doesn't work for my android app?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, layout

I have ran my android app in debug mode (eclipse).

I then ran `sdk/tools/viewhierarchy`

my device is detected, but it doesn't have an expanding arrow.

what am i doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For security reasons, Hierarchy Viewer only works on developer versions of the Android platform.

You can use Hierarchy Viewer with your app on any device by adding [ViewServer](https://github.com/romainguy/ViewServer) to your app.

Answer (score 0):

Hierarchy viewer **works only on emulators and on rooted devices**.